# How to load image on edit form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have form where I edit some information. This include also one field for image. The problem is that I can't load the link(or image) to the image and when I submit the form and I didn't provide new image old one got erased from DB which is normal because I provide empty field. The question is what to do in this case?
this is my form

```
if ( !empty($_POST)) 
            {
            // keep track post values
                $name = $_POST['name'];
                            $image = $_POST['image'];
                $text = $_POST['text'];
                $adress = $_POST['adress'];

                    // update data
                    $pdo = Database::connect();
                    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                    $sql = "UPDATE rest set name = ?, image = ?, text = ?, adress = ? WHERE id = ?";
                    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                    $q->execute(array($name,$image,$text,$adress,$id));
                    Database::disconnect();
                    //header("Location: index.php");
                    echo "<code>Done!</code>";
            } 
            else 
            {
                $pdo = Database::connect();
                $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM rest where id = ?";
                $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $q->execute(array($rest_id));
                $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $name = $data['name'];
                            $image= $data[image];
                $text = $data['text'];
                $adress = $data['adress'];
                Database::disconnect();
            }
       ?>
                <form role="form" action="" method="post">
        <!-- Form Name -->
        <legend>Редакция на ресторант</legend>

        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input value="<?php echo !empty($name)?$name:'';?>" id="name" name="name"  class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>

        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="text">Text</label>
            <input value="<?php echo !empty($text)?$text:'';?>" id="text" name="text" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="image">Image</label>
            <input value="<?php echo !empty($image)?$image:'';?>" id="image" name="image" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="adress">Adress</label>
            <input value="<?php echo !empty($adress)?$adress:'';?>" id="adress" name="adress" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>

    </form>
```

As you can see when the form is opened I check and get in fields data from DB and I edit what I need. This way if for example I don't want to edin `Name` I wont submit empty field. The problem is with the image field. How should I make this? It didn't apear link/name or whatever on that position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't update your image field if it's empty or null, just change your sql removing the image field from update:

```
if ($image != null && $image != ''){
    $sql = "UPDATE rest set name = ?, image = ?, text = ?, adress = ? WHERE id = ?";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($name,$image,$text,$adress,$id));
}
else {
    $sql = "UPDATE rest set name = ?, text = ?, adress = ? WHERE id = ?";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($name,$text,$adress,$id)); //remove image from here too..
}
```

Comment: Yeah, and if I actually whant to put new image?

Comment: When I don't put image save `text` on it field and text become empty. And also after I've got undefined variable on `$image = $_POST['image'];` when I hit update button

Comment: Yes, this way looks like is working. Just one last thing why I get `Notice: Undefined index: image in..` when i press update? Before that I don't get it

Comment: In that way you can put a new image or leave it empty

Comment: And how to get rid of the notice?

Comment: $image= $data[image]; has no quotes, replace it with $image= $data['image']; in the else statement

Comment: Still same. The notice is from `IF` block. Here and is only on the image... `if ( !empty($_POST)) 
            {
            // keep track post values
                $name = $_POST['name'];
                            $image = $_POST['image'];
                $text = $_POST['text'];
                $adress = $_POST['adress'];`

Comment: try this:  $image = isset($_POST['image']) ? $_POST['image'] : null;

Comment: Yes, that's way didn't get Notice. Thank you

Comment: Well, I'm sorry to bother you again but if I put new image it didn't upload the new one.

Comment: And is going into second sql in else block and got error because `'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens'` I've trying to upload new image but there is no variable for this in second sql

Comment: I think you need to count "?" and pass the same number of variables to the method.

Comment: I've made them equal. Also I've put the missing part for the image upload but the image never go into database and into the folder.

Comment: If you want to upload a file you have to use <input type="file"...> and enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute in your form element, like this example http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: This is what I get now `Notice: Undefined variable: web_image in` here `if ($web_image != null && $web_image != '')`